# Presenting the ViewController in full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, ios13, presentviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller in a button action as follows,

```
PromptController *obj = [[[PromptController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PromptController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj]autorelease];    
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
[AVSession stopRunning];
```

But it is not presenting on the full screen of the phone. It is presenting as follows
[image]

How to present it on the full screen. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 13 the default presentation style has changed. If you want iOS 12 presentation style, you can change the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen`.

Swift Version

```
navigation.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Objective C

```
navigation.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```